# How to put my phone in dim mode in Android?

Tags: android

I want to put my phone in dim mode using my application. It seems phone's home screen will be in deem mode. If I going to use Power Manager class then it will drain battery. How can I do this then?  Can any one give some sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I just update the Android Default Settings,

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(cr,android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 1);
```

Note: here 1 is value for dim (low) (values 0 t0 250) , and cr is ContentResolver's object

For this you have to mentioned permission in manifest file,

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

Comment: the code is right but Google hides some API so the code won't take effect until you turn off  the screen and then turn on once.

Comment: actually,you can set the value from 0 to 255

Comment: @Huang - Thanks for comment, I am using this in my galaxy tab and I don't get any difficulty(as you mentioned) till now. Its work fine.

Comment: on my Motorola phone, the code works that way.Perhaps depends on the rom. But I don't think it is like a SCREEN LOCK , since the screen still responds to the touch event.

Comment: @Huang - yes you are right, in 0 its also worked. Sorry for that comment. Actually I had a problem in manage that value.

Comment: yes..the screen is going in dim mode using the above code. But i want some more features. I mean when it is in dim mode, if anyone call or any sms or mail came, it should not blink or should not notify.

Comment: So how to lock the screen then??

Comment: @Arindam Mukherjee - I think its your another question.